# Jenkins build pauses forever on stage with 'No steps'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, terraform, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use the `terraform destroy` command in this 'Destroy' stage to destroy my aws terraform stack. When I run this in jenkins and blue ocean it says that the stage has no steps and then it just pauses forever on this stage.

I've tried adding a `while { branch 'master'}` in this stage to force this to run, and also I have tried adding other code to this stage like an echo command. I also tried extracting the code in the catch block to force something to run in the stage, however that did not work either. In the beginning of the Jenkins build the user will select if they want to apply or destroy a terraform stack. If they select to destroy then the environment string variable `STEPS` will have its 21st or 22nd index equal to t to represent "true". I am using this to check whether the destroy script should be executed. I tested this indexing and this part of the code works.

```
            steps {
                echo "Entering destroy block"
                script {
                    if(STEPS[21] == "t" || STEPS[22]=="t") {
                    echo "I entered the if block!"
                    try {
                        sh 'no | ./terraform destroy'

                    }
                    catch(err) {
                        def destrInput = input(id: 'destroying', message: 'Would you like to destroy the stack?', parameters: [ [$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: false, description: 'CHECK WHAT YOU ARE DESTROYING ABOVE', name: 'confirm'] ])
                        sh './terraform destroy -input=false -auto-approve'
                        echo "The stack has been destroyed."
                    }
                    def destrInput = input(id: 'destroying', message: 'Would you like to destroy the stack?', parameters: [ [$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: false, description: 'CHECK WHAT YOU ARE DESTROYING ABOVE', name: 'confirm'] ])
                    sh './terraform destroy -input=false -auto-approve'
                    echo "The stack has been destroyed."
                    return
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "I did nothing in the destroy block except print this message. "
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want this 'Destroy stage' to run `terraform destroy` and automatically pass no into it, in the try block, so then it will output what will be destroyed without actually destroying it. I put this in a try block because if not it throws an error and fails the build. After this, I want the catch block to execute so it will prompt the user and ask them if they want to destroy the stack. The user can view the output from the `terraform destroy` command called in the `try` block so then they can view what will be destroyed. Then when the user clicks to approve the destroy, Jenkins will automatically destroy the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a [plan](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#destroy) for destroy without actually destroying the resources by running `terraform plan -destroy`